# PHP to JS: printing js variable (like PHP echo) compatible with AJAX responseText?

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

I'm using W3 Schools' AJAX PHP Example (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp) as the foundation for my **guestlist web app** that uses data stored in *LocalStorage*, rather than MySQL database, in order for users to be able to search while offline. Now I'm trying to finalize the search guest part.

This is how it works (and *differs* from the example above):

1. (index.php). Placing / mirroring all records from MySQL db into
   javascript arrays
2. (index.php). Storing the above mentioned js arrays in LocalStorage
3. (index.php). By using the AJAX GET code used in the example,
   sending the searched item to getData.html (a html file instead of
   php file as W3 does)
4. (getData.html). Successfully getting the searched item through the
   URL parameter
5. (getData.html). Looping through and matching values like in the
   above example (code rewriten in javascript).

**BUT** here ends my success. The AJAX code is identical to the one in the above supplied example (except of course the reference to getData.html), and everything else seems to be working so I won't bother you with my entire code. In the example mentioned, at the very buttom of the PHP-file it says

```
    //output the response
    echo $response;
```

This is where javascript seems to be failing. I've desperately been trying to echo / print the response but for some reason, **it doesn't get returned to index.php properly.** The only way to force it to display at least something is to either use php echo, or simply just write plain html text somewhere in the getData document within the HTML tags. I've also tried getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML = "hello"; to see if it works but with no success.

**The most obvious way** to do this would be to simply replace echo $response with the equivalent in js:

```
    document.write(response);
```

but whatever document.write prints, nothing's dipslayed. The div in which the "hint" is supposed to pop up is *yet empty*. I've googled solutions, different ways of printing js variables with no further success. Perhaps, **document.write is not "compatible" with XML or AJAX responseText?** There must be a simple solution to this. Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Please [consider using sources other than w3schools.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: There's way too much information here.  I suggest you step back and diagnose a little more carefully, to more precisely determine the basic problem. Boil it down. At the critical part you say you use "echo $response" but this is where the javascript is failing.  This makes no sense to me.  The echo is a php statement. How is that causing the javascript to fail? Also: It doesn't make sense to say **it doesn't get returned to index.php properly**.  Index.php is a script that runs and EMITS output.  Nothing is returned to it.  You need to do some more analysis on this one.

Comment: I wont argue with you on that one, however if it were an uncomplex problemet easy to explain I would have found the answer aready. And please don't be all anal about the expressions, rather try to understand what i mean. 

The bottom line is simple though:
I CANT get javascript to print a variable in the same way PHP echo does, in order for it to work. I know nothing is actually "returned" from getData to index, but as shown the AJAX part is set du grab whatver's printed in getData but it won twork. docuemtn.write(respons) doesn't print the variable in the same was php echo does.

Comment: have you tried using JS console on chrome or firefox to see if the javascript is throwing any errors? Also I hope you're going for getData.html on the same domain as index.php, because ajax doesn't work across different domains.

Answer (score 0):

php is of course a server-side language that emits a page and runs on your back end.
js is of course a client-side language that runs on the user's front end.
document.write() is the proper function for emitting client-side text; it runs at page load time.  Example:

```
<b>My domain is: <script>document.write(document.domain);</script></b>
```

properly gives

> **My domain is: www.mydomain.com**